# cannot call sun.security.tools.keytool.Main from within maven test units

Tags: maven, java-8, keytool, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting (oracle jdk 8)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at ....KeyStoreCreationTest.test(KeyStoreCreationTest.java:41)
```

for

```
    Class<?> keytoolClazz = Class.forName("sun.security.tools.keytool.Main");
    Method mainMethod = keytoolClazz.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
    log.info(mainMethod);
    Object[] params = new String[]{"-help"};
    mainMethod.invoke(null, params);
```

or

```
    mainMethod.invoke(null, new String[]{"-help"});
```

If I try to call the method directly, it says there is no such package.

Any ideas?

The log statement outputs:

```
public static void sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Method.invoke` expects an arrays of `Object`s, representing an (almost) arbitrary number of arguments. The `main` method expects a *single* argument which has an array type.

So you may invoke it using

```
mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{ new String[]{"-help"} });
```

or, since it is a *varargs* method:

```
mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object)new String[]{"-help"});
```

In the latter case, casting it to `Object` forces the compiler to treat it as a single argument, which will get wrapped into an array automatically (which is what varargs methods are about).

Note that you can use the varargs feature on the lookup as well:

```
Method mainMethod = keytoolClazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
```

The type will get wrapped into an array automatically.